# Taxes: What is the correct way to file freelance income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, small-business, foreign-income

I've been living and working remotely as a freelance software developer in America, but for European clients. Each month I write them an invoice for my contract hours and they pay me (in EUR, if that matters). I simply write the invoice and receive a transfer.

But when it comes time to file my US taxes, I don't receive any additional documentation from them. To be more specific, because I'm an independent contractor I don't get a W-2, but unlike the American clients I've worked with, I'm also not getting any kind of 1099 form from them.

So my main question is, what is the correct way for me to report this income on my US taxes?

Comment: Does this help? https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/156270/how-to-properly-calculate-usd-income-when-paid-in-foreign-currency-like-eur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 1099 is not necessary. As a business owner (which is what you are as an independent contractor), you are required to report all of your revenue, whether or not you receive a 1099 for it.

If you haven’t set up any other kind of legal structure for your business, it is a sole proprietorship, which is reported on your tax return each year on a [Schedule C](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-schedule-c-form-1040). Here you will report all of your business revenue and expenses and calculate your business profit, which is what you are taxed on.

Comment: You'll also need to do schedule SE for self-employment tax (the equivalent of FICA).